# Docker: Django & Postgres > How to connect

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#connect-the-database) here to setup Docker with Django. It works perfectly now and also my Postgres database seems to be installed. Where it fails for me is connecting with Postico (macOS) to my Postgres that's running in the container. Anyone who has experience in that, is it possible to connect 'from the outside' with eg. Postico to this container?

Currently I typed in:
Host localhost
User postgres
Password postgres

But I am not sure about the password, as in the tutorial I never set any.

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for composeexample project.


Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XYZ'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'composeexample.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'composeexample.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: I think that out-of-the-box postgres db server does not allow connections expect for from localhost.  A quick google search shows https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html  Also you'll have to figure out how to get your docker container to "expose" postgres's port.

Comment: @Jon Programmer can you add your docker-compose file and your\ settings.py file?

Comment: @ RedCricket I actually want to connect from my localhost, but not via terminal, but via Postico as I can easier edit database entries there.

@JPG I added it.

Comment: Can you add the error you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said in comments:

> I actually want to connect from my localhost, but not via terminal, but via Postico as I can easier edit database entries there.

If you wish to connect from localhost, you must expose the ports for pgsql.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    expose:
    - "5432"
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

If you're on Linux, then you have to get your `db` IP with `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id` and connect through the IP.

On Mac you can use `localhost` to access it.